# ABBYY Flexicapture connect to database

Tags: ocr, abbyy

I have often run database queries in ABBYY Flexicapture by connecting to dll methods that contained the database calls. I would like to have the ability to connect directly in the ABBYY rules, if possible. A relatively recent update added the ability to write the rules in C#, so I'm assuming it's possible to do this.

I have added System.Data as a .Net Reference in the Document Definition properties, but I get "The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" when I run this line of code:

`SqlConn = new SqlConnection("[My Connection String]");`

I have tried adding

`using System.Data.SqlConnection`

above that line and it says SqlConnection does not exist in System.Data.

Has anyone had success in doing this?

Comment: Could you please help me out on my question ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666948/summarize-table-using-c-sharp-and-jscript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.data.SqlClient
```