# Summarize table using C# and JScript

Tags: c#, .net, jscript

I've written code in C# to summarize values of `InvoiceTable` and move those summarized values to to `GroupTable` in Abbyy FlexiCapture. The Software is comparatively new and does not show any error when I run it.

There are two sets of code to be written:

1. In TechField.
2. In EventHandlers.

`InvoiceTable` consists of:

- TariffNumber
- ShipQty
- Amount
- COO

`GroupTable` consists of:

- HSCode
- Qty
- Amt
- CountryOO

EventHandlers code is as follows (C#):

```
if (ChangedStates.Has(7)) {
    int currentRow = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Document.Field("Invoice2\\InvoiceTable").Items.Count; i++) {
        if (Document.Field("Invoice2\\InvoiceTable").Cell("TariffNumber", i).Value == "") {
            Document.Field("Invoice2\\GroupTable").Cell("HSCode", currentRow).Value = Document.Field("Invoice2\\InvoiceTable").Cell("TariffNumber", i).Value;
            Document.Field("Invoice2\\GroupTable").Cell("Amt", currentRow).Value = Document.Field("Invoice2\\InvoiceTable").Cell("Amount", i).Value;
            Document.Field("Invoice2\\GroupTable").Cell("Qty", currentRow).Value = Document.Field("Invoice2\\InvoiceTable").Cell("ShipQty", i).Value;
            currentRow++;
        }
    }
}
```

TechField is as follows (JScript):

```
for (i = 0; i < Field("ShipQty").Items.Count - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < Field("ShipQty").Items.Count; j++) {
        // if same new items are found
        if (Field("TariffNumber").Items(i).Value == Field("TariffNumber").Items(j).Value && Field("CoO").Items(i).Value == Field("CoO").Items(j).Value)
        {
            // summarise quantities
            Field("ShipQty").Items(i).Value = parseInt(Field("ShipQty").Items(i).Value) + parseInt(Field("ShipQty").Items(j).Value);

            // and weights
            Field("Amount").Items(i).Value = parseFloat(Field("Amount").Items(i).Value) + parseFloat(Field("Amount").Items(j).Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Condition:

In the `InvoiceTable`, where ever `TariffNumber` and `COO` are equal, values of `ShipQty` and Amount should be summarized and put into `GroupTable`.

The code does not show any errors but does not give the output as well. Would be great if anyone of you can help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is adding a summary section to the document definition. This may require you to create a document set.

I've found it easier to create rules which are checked when the field is recognised. There's some info here:  https://help.abbyy.com/en-us/flexicapture/12/distributed_administrator/docsets_settings/